# SFML Text Doesn't Draw On Screen Along with many other elements

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm currently trying to learn how to use the sfml api, but my whole draw function doesn't work and doesn't display anything. I did put breakpoints and verified that the program does go through that function, and it does, but it still doesn't work.

This is my function that doesn't work :

```
void GameStateStart::draw() {

    this->game->window.clear();

    /*Modify the colour of the background*/
    background.getRectangle().setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);
    background.drawObject(&game->window);

    /*Create the font for the text*/
    sf::Font font;
    font.loadFromFile("Pacifco.ttf");

    /*Test*/
    sf::Text title2;
    title2.setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    title2.setFont(font);
    title2.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(300, 100));
    title2.setString("Tic Tac SFML");
    title2.setCharacterSize(25);
    this->game->window.draw(title2);

    /*Edit title text objects*/
    title.getText()->setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    title.getText()->setFont(font);
    title.getText()->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(300, 100));
    title.getText()->setString("Tic Tac SFML");

    /*Edit instructions text object*/

    instructions.getText()->setFillColor(sf::Color::Blue);
    instructions.getText()->setFont(font);
    instructions.getText()->setPosition(sf::Vector2f(300, 450));
    instructions.getText()->setString("Press the spacebar to continue");

    /*draw the 2 text objects*/
    title.drawObject(&this->game->window);
    instructions.drawObject(&this->game->window);

    this->game->window.display();

    return;
}
```

Comment: Does `font.loadFromFile()` return `true`?

Comment: @al-eax but OP said even the background doesnt render

Comment: @al-eax I though I would try bt since nothing else renders, I don't think its that

Comment: We use the function `sf::RenderTarget::draw`[1] to draw on window. This is what most tutorials suggest... thay may help?

[1] : http://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1RenderTarget.php#a12417a3bcc245c41d957b29583556f39

Comment: @al-eax So, like what I did with the test title where I did `window.draw(title2)` ?

Comment: Could you put all GameStateStart class here. And I think main function is in this class too. If Im wrong, put the main function also. By the way it's not efficient that reading file on every draw.